Animation of one component affects other components
I have the following layout where


The Topbar component can be shown/hidden and slides up/down
The Bottombar component can be shown/hidden and slides up/down
The Wrapper components acts as a slider and goes from left to right

The issue, as shown in the video, is that alternating between slides affects the Topbar component and Bottombar components.
https://imgur.com/oOW8JAX
